# How to study python to take part in GSoC?

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I have learnt the basics from learnpythonthehardway.org/book and now I'm unable to understand the codes and libraries method of my favorite projects on github.

What should I do now in step by step manner so that I become capable enough to contribute and hence take part in GSoC no matter how much time it takes?
Some says I should practise python questions on hackerrank and other says I should work on my own project and learn from it. Which should I follow?

Comment: perhaps, you should ask this on quora.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to learn Python I know YouTube has a lot of fantastic resources. Since you've already read *Learn Python the Hard Way*, I would suggest you look for YouTube videos where the host is creating a project (Look for something which interests you), and follow along until you come across something you don't know. Research it, rinse and repeat. As a bonus, you'll end up with some neat Python projects in the end, too.

Another great way to get some Python experience is to find different sources of tutorials. I learned Python from Codecademy, but there are plenty out there.

However, all said, there is simply nothing like figuring things out yourself. Set a goal - think of a project to create - and get as far as you can, and look for as many opportunities to learn as possible. That's my favorite way to learn.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Dylan, YouTube hosts a lot of Python tutorials which are helpful for learning more about Python.

Additionally, I would invest your time in reading some eBooks. They have a wealth of knowledge that can expand your horizons beyond learning the basics of Python and personally I found it to be a huge help in understanding the language. Read these and take some good notes.

- *Python Cookbook (Second or Third Edition)* by David Beazley
- *Automate
  the Boring Stuff With Python* by Al Sweigart
- *A Byte of Python* by
  Swaroop C.H.
- *Test-Driven Development with Python* by Henry Percival
- *Real Python for the Web* by Michael Herman

Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I use C/C++ language to develop monitor and control software for hardware device for many years. Recently I started to learn Python for some reasons, so I also wondering which way is the best way to study a new language. My learning materials are two books, Learning Python and Programming Python. I think the language's foundational concepts are really important. As my experience in C/C++, the most frequent book I use in my work is the first one I studied in University, as that book focused on the foundational concepts. So I think the most important thing is understanding the foundational concepts,and the best way is typing it and test it by your hand, not only seeing the example.